# Flocking Robots

Tags: robotics

For a project we want to create a group of 'flocking' robots.

Between 5 - 10 robots to be interacting with each other -> what is the best value robot for this kind of project.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Formica](http://warrantyvoidifremoved.com/formica), they have tiny relatively cheap robots.

Comment: Is there a place to buy these from? From the site it looks like they are still putting together kits???

Comment: It looks like they've been putting together the kits for about 18 months. But the schematics etc are available for free.

Comment: Plus right on cue they've just shown up on the Makezine Blog - http://blog.makezine.com/archive/2010/01/open_source_swarm_robot_project.html